# Automatic 2d tileset textures

Tags: 2d, tilemap, tiles, maps, texture-atlas

I am currently trying around with automatically generating a dungeon.

I'd like to use this tileset https://opengameart.org/content/a-blocky-dungeon

TLDR: how do I automatically apply a texture to a tile on the grid.

The grid consists of void, floor and wall tiles for now. In order for the walls to look good, I spaced out the rooms enough so there is at least one void tile between two wall tiles.

I can't find a decent solution for the double-height walls. There are so many possible outcomes for these pillars.. for example the original tileset does not include "tee" tiles as you can see in my messed up image below.

The only question I found was this one [How do you handle uneven tiles while rendering a tile map?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/how-do-you-handle-uneven-tiles-while-rendering-a-tile-map)
I am currently drawing the wall tile texture as a 16x32 texture, anchored at the bottom.

**Do I need to generate every upper wall of a room as a 2 high wall?**

My way of assigning the texture to a tile is quite ugly, I have a huge json like this:

```
"w:wall,e:wall,s:void,n:floor": {
    "x": 6,
    "y": 3
},
...
```

Is there a standard way of assigning a tileset to a grid? bitmasking doesn't seem to be right here

[image: dungeon]

Comment: Bitmasking is exactly what you need, it's just that you need a 3x4 neighbourhood for this tileset. Each tile cares about the value of the tiles above, left, right, and up to *two* tiles below.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you! So that would mean I would have to generate every upper wall of a room as a 2 high row of wall tiles?

Comment: It looks to me like you have one row of "wall" tiles and one row of "wall cap" tiles.